# T-test for two independent variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean, standard-deviation, standard-error

[image: Samples of apples from LA and NY]

This image show sample taken from LA and NY for apple price. When I want to do a hypothesis test if the mean of NY price > LA price, I was saying that my NULL hypothesis is 
$H0 : μ_{NY} - μ_{LA} > 0$, 
but what if I wanted to make a test that NY price > LA price by 20%, will the NULL hypothesis becomes 
$H0 : 1.2 \times μ_{NY} - μ_{LA} > 0$, 
Or what should I do ? , below, there is some data I calculated for the samples.

[image: Statistics data for the samples]

Comment: Multiply NY apples column by 1.2 and and compare with LA apples?

Comment: I also thought about it but, i don't know if it is valid or not.

Comment: You switched null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis.

Comment: @user158565 , Why!?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis

Comment: @user158565 , Oh I see, so the opposite of what I want to test is my null hypothesis ?.

Comment: More generally, The null hypothesis is the current believe and you want to prove it is incorrect. The alternative hypothesis is the new theory you want to establish to replace the old one in case you prove the old one is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

1. Multiply LA apple prices by 1.2 and do a bivariate T test.
2. Do a log transform of the apple price. $P_{NY} > 1.2 P_{LA}$ implies that $\log(P_{NY}) - \log(P_{LA}) > \log(1.2)$. You can fit a linear regression model with an offset term to test that hypothesis.
3. Multiply the 95% CI for the LA apple prices by 1.2 and inspect whether the scaled-LA price interval and NY price interval mutually overlap.

Comment: method 1: If original data met homogeneity of variance, method 1 destroys the homogeneity. Method 2: If original data following normal distribution, method 2 destroys the normality.

Comment: @user158565 1) use unequal variance assumption (I use this *de facto* for absolutely every analysis I do). 2) Wrong. Normal is scale family. Worried about heterogeneity? Robust standard errors, when data too few can be conservative.

Comment: Why do log transform?.

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanAkram because of the algebraic properties. A test of log difference is a test of a ratio. You really want to know if the ratio is greater than 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Y_i$ (price) follows normal distribution $N(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$.

Fit a linear model:

$$Y=\beta_N X_{1i}+\beta_L X_{2i} + \epsilon$$ where $X_{i1} = 1$ if $i^{th}$ price is from New York, = 0 if from LA, $X_{2_i}=1$ if $i^{th}$ price is from LA, = 0 otherwise.

It is straightforward to test the null hypothesis: $H_0: \beta_N - 1.2 \beta_L = 0$, because it is very common form of hull hypothesis ($L\beta = 0$) in the linear model.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most pragmatic solution, but it is a solution.  Use a Bayesian comparison.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(brms)
library(tidybayes)

nyapples<- tibble(price = c(3.80, 3.76, 3.87, 3.99,  4.02, 4.25, 4.13, 3.98, 3.99, 3.62),
                  place = 'NY')


lapples<- tibble(price = c(3.02, 3.22, 3.24, 3.02, 3.06, 3.15, 3.81, 3.44),
                 place = 'LA')

apples = bind_rows(nyapples, lapples)


model = brm(price ~ place,
            data = apples)


model %>% 
  recover_types(apples) %>% 
  spread_draws(b_Intercept,b_placeNY) %>% 
  mutate(ratio = (b_placeNY+b_Intercept)/b_Intercept)
```

Here is a KDE of the resulting distribution of `ratio`

[image]

The model estimates that the price of New York apples exceeds the price of LA apples by least 20% with probability ~62%.